# Modifying an existing module in linux kernel

Tags: linux, module, kernel, beagleboard, recompile

I am using `g_file_storage` as driver on my `embedded linux` to pose it as mass storage for any usb host.I have done that well!!

Now I need to do more .... is to capture eject event on usb device ..which is a functionality not given by `g_file_storage` till now.

I have got this `function fsg_suspend()` in `g_file_storage driver` ...Its is the routine that gets called when a Windows USB host does `"Safely remove hardware"`.....

i am thinking of adding a simple printk to send simple message in `/var/log/message` 
in `fsg_suspend` function which i will watch from user space on `BeagleBoard`.....

but i m into a very basic kernel programming doubt ...if you can help me out ....

i have written simple kernel modules ..which is lets say `module.c` file an
i use simple make command to compile it then `modprobe/insmod` to insert it and then i use it ......
**this is about a module totally written by me.**

and

i have also configured a module as option M in config file while recompiling kernel  ..
then i do make , make modules , make `modules_install` , `make_install` 
then we use  `modprobe` to use that particular feature ..pl Correct me if i am wrong ....

But here this module is a kernel module , if i make a change to it , Then ........

can i just recompile it using its makefile ...and do modprobe ...?
but this [Makefile](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/gadget/Makefile) doesnt seem to support this idea ..

will it interfere with already present copy of this module in running kernel ?
Or
will i have to recompile kernel?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand most of the first half of the query.  The question is tagged Linux and kernel, so why is there so much about Windows?

If I understand correctly, you'll have to disable the existing device driver.  The most straightforward means is to rebuild the kernel without it.  Then use the `insmod` and `rmmod` commands to load and unload the new driver.

I can't tell from the details you've provided, but maybe there is a way for the new driver to coexist alongside the old one.  If it does not need an IRQ, or it can use a separate one, then you can create new device nodes and use it independently of the existing driver.

Comment: There's only one line about windows isn't there?